# MySQL INSERT query doesn't add any data

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a node app that inserts some data into a database. The problem is that when I run the `INSERT INTO` query, the data isn't added to the database. After running the `INSERT` query, I ran a `SELECT` one to test, and it returned an empty list. I also queried the database from DataGrip and that also showed the `items` table as completely empty.

This is my code, which as far I can tell is correct:

```js
let items = require("../data/items.json");
for (let [categoryName, itemList] of Object.entries(items)) {
    if (categoryName !== "all") {
        for (let item of itemList) {
            let itemInfo = Object.entries(item);
            bot.con.query(`INSERT INTO items (id, desc, category) VALUES ('${itemInfo[0][0]}', '${itemInfo[0][1]}', '${categoryName}')`, (err, rows) => {
                // do nothing
            });
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: MySQL is now returning a syntax error, although I am not sure where in my query the error is.

This is the error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, category) VALUES ('STOCK_OF_STONKS', 'Stock Of Stonks', 'oddities')' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
    at Object.hourly (/Volumes/NO NAME/College/Computing/NEA/hypstats/utils/gen.js:32:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, category) VALUES ('STOCK_OF_STONKS', 'Stock Of Stonks', 'oddities')' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO items (id, desc, category) VALUES ('STOCK_OF_STONKS', 'Stock Of Stonks', 'oddities')"
}
```

Comment: What happens if you check the `err` parameter in your callback?

Comment: Logging `err` seems to have printed the mystery error that was hiding for some reason. It says there is an error in my syntax, although I am not sure where that is?

Answer (score 0):

use it:

```
bot.con.query("insert into items set ?", {id: X, desc: Y, category: Z})
```

X , Y and Z are your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your program to use this code.

```js
 let itemInfo = Object.entries(item);
 let query = `INSERT INTO items (id, desc, category) VALUES ('${itemInfo[0][0]}', '${itemInfo[0][1]}', '${categoryName}')`;
 bot.con.query(query, (err, rows) => {
       if (err) return console.error ('query error', query, err);
 });
```

You'll see your INSERT query and probably be able to spot your problem.  Your problem is probably a data string containing a `'` character somewhere.

To fix it, change your code to something like this (not debugged)

```js
 let itemInfo = Object.entries(item);
 let query = 'INSERT INTO items (id, desc, category) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
 bot.con.query(query, [itemInfo[0][0], itemInfo[0][1], categoryName],
               (err, rows) => {
                 if (err) return console.error ('query error', query, err);
               });
```

This is a so-called *parameterized query*. It avoids the `'` problem and avoids [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/).